# Using @FieldMap and @Part in single request in Retrofit2 gets java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is allowed.for method

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

This might seem similar to earlier questions but none actually answers my question.
I need to Post multiple fields and multiple images in one request using retrofit2 and i'm getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is allowed.for method xxx
```

i'm using

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
```

since @Field requires @FormUrlEncoded and @Part requires @Multipart. 
the more logical thing to do is to remove the @FormUrlEncoded annotation, but how do i go from there.
Now the question is how do i go about the task to achieve sending my post in a single request.

here's the interface

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPost(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map,
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part image1,
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part image2,
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part image3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPost(
        @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> descriptions,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> images);
```

use this interface.

Comment: Why there is RequestBody in Map can't we use String in it

Comment: Yes you can use it. But for that you have to use string converter 
Have a look at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520012/get-string-response-body-from-retrofit2)