# Retrofit request @Part and @FieldMap together

Tags: android, retrofit

I'd like to send a post request to server & I have multiple key-value params and a list of files like so:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php")
Call<MyObjResponse> myCall(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files, @FieldMap Map<String, String> params);
```

I get a error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. (parameter #1)
>           for method IRestApi.pushLocalChangesWithMultipartCall
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:592)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:336)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
>           at $Proxy5.pushLocalChangesWithMultipartCall(Unknown Source)

I tryed to put `@Multipart` in place of `@FormUrlEncoded` and error become:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @FieldMap parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #2)
>           for method IRestApi.pushLocalChangesWithMultipartCall
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:567)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:336)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
>           at $Proxy5.pushLocalChangesWithMultipartCall(Unknown Source)

p.s. `POST` is a mult I can't use `PUT`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Multipart` then you should use `@PartMap` instead of `@FieldMap`

Here is an example in another answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136931/8479132