# How to convert Map<String, String> to RequestBody?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

Using Retrofit 2.4.0, I am making a `@Multipart` `@POST` request. I am sending a file as `@Part` along with some metadata as`@PartMap`. This is what the call looks like.

```
@Multipart
@POST("https://8hoot.com/my-path")
Single<Response<UploadMediaResponseModel>> uploadMedia(
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> metadata,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart
);
```

There is another `Map<String, String>`, let us call it `subMetaMap`, which contains related key-value pairs.

**How can I store this `subMetaMap` in the `@PartMap` `metadata`?** Something like shown below.

```
RequestBody subMetaMapAsRequestBody; // Convert subMetaMap to RequestBody
metadata.put("subMeta", subMetaMapAsRequestBody);
```

---

Currently, I am using the following method.

```
for (String s : subMetaMap.keySet()) {
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, subMetaMap.get(s));
    metadata.put(s, requestBody);
}
```

**This is not the desired solution as I want the whole `subMetaMap` as the `RequestBody` not its individual key-value pairs**

---

**Edit 1**- The backend team doesn't take different MIME types during `Multipart` request. So sending `JSON`, `MessagePack`, etc. is not an option.

Comment: Just check out this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap.

Comment: @buzzingsilently Thanks for the resource but it doesn't solve this issue

Comment: you should convert your second map's values to RequestBody and r the map as another partmap with the api request

Comment: @AnkitMehta In Wireshark it looks like that all different `PartMap`s are merged into one after the request is complete. I will inspect this behavior in the backend application and return soon.

Comment: sure. let me know if it works....

Comment: @AnkitMehta Wireshark's observation extended to the backend application as well. The `PartMap`s were merged when the complete request was received.

Comment: So, it worked ??

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182945/discussion-between-potatopc-and-ankit-mehta).

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you have following map you want to send this data to retrofit request body

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
map.put("key4", "value4");
```

Following is the URL Request method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/yourapiname")
Call<ResponseObj> methodName(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> yourHasMapObject);
```

If you want to add file and hashmap then use the following method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("yourapiname")
Call<ResponseObj> methodName(@HeaderMap HashMap<String, String> yourHasMapObject, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Comment: Then I will have to do another request for the `filePart`?

Comment: Using `FieldMap` in `Multipart` throws an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820762/using-fieldmap-and-part-in-single-request-in-retrofit2-gets-java-lang-illegala#40136931

Comment: got it, one other option is use the header and in request body send the multipart? can you go with this solution?

Comment: Good approach. I think this might work. Just to make sure we are on the same page. You are suggesting that instead of having `subMeta` key and `subMetaMap` value pair in `@PartMap`, I should put it in the header and get it from there in the backend application. Is this right?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look on that, I am confident it will work, I am also using this approach.

Comment: `@HeaderMap` will work, I have another concern. A large header can cause HTTP server to drop connections. How do you deal with this?

Comment: Apache default limit is 8KB, in IIS its 16K for headers, do you think you will be sending more data than that? I believe 8kb data is very large in text

Comment: I think this would be true for a map too.

Comment: retrofit will just convert your map into json string in key-value pair nothing else. If I am not wrong you may send upto 8k characters for apache and larger for other servers and it depends upon default setting of your server as well.

Comment: kindly mark as answer if you found solution and it could help others. Atleas if it helped you personally please upvote it.

Comment: True, and the map's size is barely KiBs

Comment: Sure. I will upvote but I think the original question is still unanswered. So, I won't accept the answer. Hope you understand and don't mind

Comment: No worries at all, accept it as answer if its worthy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182946/discussion-between-potatopc-and-kunal-mahajan).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the other map in the same way you are passing the first map.

First, convert the values of second map from `String` to `RequestBody` and then your request should be like follows:

```
@Multipart
@POST("https://8hoot.com/my-path")
Single<Response<UploadMediaResponseModel>> uploadMedia(
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> metadata,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> anotherMetaData,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart
);
```