# Get Retrofit Response as String

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an api that gives result in something like:

if okay : `OK ID:1234567`

not okay: `2 <br>(Please Type something)`

Now i want to receive this in my android app using retrofit , one way i can think of is getting response in `String` and manually checking about error or not error scenario , But i cannot find a better way to do this :

These SO question are not explaining the solution enough to replicate:
[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589588/retrofit-get-string-response) , [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520012/get-string-response-body-from-retrofit2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Out of the box Retrofit supports using OkHttp's `ResponseBody` type. `ResponseBody` is basically an abstraction on "just bytes" and has a method called `string()` which will consume the body as a `String`.
- You can add the [`converters-scalars` artifact](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) and add the `ScalarsConverterFactory` to your instance which will allow using `String` as your response type.

Comment: first method make sense to me , and i got it's code example from one of the question thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to the first way. Perhaps it will be helpful for some.

Api interface:

```
public interface APIService {
@GET("api/get_info")
    Call<ResponseBody> getInfo();//import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
}
```

Api call:

```
// Retrofit service creation code skipped here
String json = retrofitService().getInfo().execute().body().string();
```

It worked for me. I use retrofit:2.1.0.